# removing largest contour from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image such as this

[image]

I am trying to detect and remove the arrow from this image so that I end up with an image that just has the text.

I tried the below approach but it isn't working

```
image_src = cv2.imread("roi.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny=cv2.Canny(gray,50,200,3)
ret, gray = cv2.threshold(canny, 10, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]
mask = np.ones(image_src.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255
cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_area], -1, 0, -1)
image = cv2.bitwise_and(image_src, image_src, mask=mask)
```

The above code seems to give me back the same image WITH the arrow.

How can I remove the arrow?

Comment: i was following this post so i used the `bitwse_and` http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/09/removing-contours-image-using-python-opencv/ . I will review my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will remove the largest contour:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_src = cv2.imread("roi.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255,0)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask = np.zeros(image_src.shape, np.uint8)
largest_areas = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest_areas[-2]], 0, (255,255,255,255), -1)
removed = cv2.add(image_src, mask)

cv2.imwrite("removed.png", removed)
```

Note, the largest contour in this case will be the whole image, so it is actually the second largest contour.

Comment: hmm the approach of using `cv2.add` to get the removed image might not work if the arrow was filled with black color though right? Do you think it would be more applicable to wide array of images if the removed image was drawn by having all remaining contours drawn?

Comment: As the mask is white, I would hope `black+white = white`. Drawing all remaining contours would definitely be an alternative approach.